# Set color of entire THREE.Geometry object

Tags: three.js, webgl

Is there a way to set the color of an entire `THREE.Geometry` object using three.js? There are a few naive ways I could do this, but none of the methods seem ideal.

I could clone a material and set a different color for each geometry. Essentially, each geometry would have a one-to-one relationship with a material. However, this would create many heavyweight material objects and possibly unnecessary extra shaders on the GPU.

I could also use a single white material and color all the faces of the geometry instead. However, there would create much repetition of the same color objects, since each geometry will only have one color but many faces.

Is there a "proper" way of doing this with three.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, this would create many heavyweight material objects and possibly unnecessary extra shaders on the GPU.

It should not. Shaders will be reused if they're the same. So creating as many materials as geometries should be ok.

Comment: Thanks. I shall use many materials then. Is there an added memory or speed benefit from cloning a base material rather than creating new ones from scratch?